# How To write to a specific part of a text file c#

Tags: c#, text-files, writetofile

I have a the following : AccountNumber , AccountName , City.
This values represents a Customer. I have 20 Customers.
I need to write to a new text file each Customer in a different line.
But the main thing : 
I need AccountNumber to start from col #10 in the line ,
AccountNumber to start from col #25 in the line , 
City to start from col #205 in the line .

I don't know how to accomplish that .
I tried several solutions that I have found but non of them were a proper solution.

Please help me.

my desired output :

```
"123456              Bob                  Tel-aviv     "
"523415              Barak                Jerusalem    " 
"  7676              Robin                Haifa        "
```

and so on...

Tried to get this result by using string.Insert Method.
With debugging it shows that the first line is good .
But for some reason , the total outcome is not what I wanted..

Thanks in advance .
Shuki

Comment: Please show an example of the output you want. You said _"I tried several solutions"_. Ok, prove it! This is why I am downvoting you.

Answer (score 2):

Just [right-pad](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padright%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) the parts to be the correct length (make sure it is not longer, and decide what to do if that occurs). Concatenate the parts and write it as a singe line.